# SSH Tunnel broker over IPV4 for machines behind CNAT

Tags: ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling, tunneling, ipv4

I am not sure if I should be asking this in Unix & Linux or Network Engineering

Here is the physical scenario

[Host 1]----[Carrier-grade NAT]---->AWS<----[Carrier-grade NAT]----[Host 2]

**Host 1** and **Host 2** are reverse ssh'ed (autossh) into an AWS Box, so they do have shell connectivity if required, and possibility to expose any other port if required.

**Host 2** pushes backup dumps to **Host 1** using SCP on regular basis. There are actually **Host2 X 10** boxes pushing the data dumps. Nearest AWS location is quite far from the location of boxes so latency is quite a lot.

Is there a possibility to use the AWS box as a rendezvous point to broker a ssh tunnel between the boxes? I am aware about the IPv6 tunnel brokers but the ISPs in the region are yet to adopt it (20 years late... duh!) I am exploring a solution bases on:

- TCP / UDP hole punching  (with practical implementation)
- UPnP / NAT-PMP service on AWS
- Using tools such as Chrome Remote Desktop, hack it to expose SSH port rather then VNC
- Any other router service.
- Any other practical approach.

Boxes are running CentOS 6/7 mostly.

Comment: Is setting up a VPN on AWS instance a viable option?

Comment: Not in this specific case, the latency issue. Also the direct connection (once brokered) will help keeping AWS bills in check.

Comment: I don't see why you need a regional IPv6 broker. I use one that's based out of the US (not my country). As long as your IPv6-in-IPv4 traffic isn't blocked I don't see the problem. I'll make this an answer if it helps you.

Comment: @roaima IPv6-in-IPv4 traffic isn't blocked. I was little discouraged after sixxs discontinued new registrations and hurricane mandated IPv6 Exam! I get it that ISPs are at fault (I already acknowledged that in the question). I would be thankful if you can refer to stable tunnel broker and steps required at both endpoints, Host 1 and Host 2.

Comment: For TCP hole punching: you should gather more informations on how your CGN is working. Perhaps by comparing with multiple tests the SSH source port seen on host1 then same source seen on aws. Do they differ?. Same for the ssh source port seen on host2 then on aws. Doing tests with a 2nd "broker" IP would be preferable too. If they differ and you can't find an algorithm able to predict what it will become, I don't see what to do. If you can find or they don't differ, then maybe its possible (TCP allows handshakes initiated with a simultaneous SYN/SYN instead of the usual SYN/SYN+ACK/...)

Comment: @A.B I got your point, getting on it. Will share profile of Host 1 & 2's NAT.

Comment: Nope, collecting pcaps at both ends and comparing. Once I have the complete details, I will edit the question and perhaps raise a bounty.

Comment: @A.B The CGN is a Port restriction cone NAT :(

Comment: Ok, but to be clear, does that mean visibles IP and port are completely unrelated to outgoing IP and port, and, if not unrelated, vary depending on destination IP? For example, if with a "rapid fire" you can see that the visible IP is the previous one + 1 most of the time, then (most of the time) it would still be previsible. Same with port. But I expect reality to be much more complicated... knowing in advance what would be the ip+port of the peer on both (CGNated) sides would be enough to punch a tcp hole

Comment: @A.B That's what I was trying to find. Found a nice python utility to do the job. Will share the results.

Comment: @A.B I was playing around with a backup IPv$ connection and teredo, turns out it is preserving the ports! Makes the job easier. Any advice on how to setup the Rendezvous server?  | Client Type             : teredo host-specific relay | Network                 : unmanaged | NAT                     : restricted (port) | NAT Special Behaviour   : UPNP: No, PortPreserving: Yes | Local Mapping           : 192.168.1.225:64556 External NAT Mapping    : x.x.x.x:64556

Comment: @A.B Found a weird behavior. Higher port requests (50000 + ) are preserving the ports I am requesting. While lower ports are incrementally random.  I doubt that could be intentional, maybe the actual connections never cross 50K on the CGN gateway.

Comment: @roaima  I also explored the IPv6 tunnel-broker only to realize that since all nodes are NATted, and not having a static IP is a bummer....

Comment: @user1263746 they weren't behind NAT last time I used tunnelbroker. That's the point of IPv6 - there is no more need for NAT.

Comment: @roaima I am missing something, I will get back to you on this.

Comment: @A.B managed to punch a hole with netcat, only to realize I cant specify local bind port for ssh/scp, any hints? or will simply cat the encrypted datadump over netcat with a listener on the server.

Comment: you surely can use `socat` (not netcat) to punch the hole, then connect ssh to it (to localhost). eg: on one side (the "server" side, so host1) : `socat TCP4-CONNECT:cgnatedhost2:cgnatedport2,bind=outgoingip1:outgoingport1 TCP4-CONNECT:localhost:22` on the "client" side `socat TCP4-CONNECT:cgnatedhost1:cgnatedport1,bind=outgoingip2:outgoingport2 TCP4-LISTEN:2222` and on the "client" you'd connect with ssh -p 2222 user1@localhost (and if the port 2222 is never used for something else, modern ssh will remember the correct remote hostid, so no need for NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you need, however:
You may expose host1 or host2 reversed local port as an external port using iptables.
So let's say you connected your host2 as ssh reversed tunnel:

```
user2@host2 $ ssh -R 9999:localhost:22 user@aws.com
```

Now you may forward the incoming port aws.com:9999 to aws [localport:9999]:
On AWS server:

```
awsuser@aws.com # iptables  -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:9999
```

And now you can connect from host2 to host1 this way:

```
user1@host1 $ ssh awsuser@aws.com -p 9999
```

Bingo. You connected this way:

[host 1] --> [aws:port 9999] --> [aws: reversed tunnel on 127.0.0.1:9999] --> [host 2]

You should remove the iptable record when this connection not used anymore:

```
awsuser@aws.com # iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:9999
```

The downside of this solution is that host2 is exposed to everyone through external port 9999. You still need to enter a password for log-in, however it is exposed.

UPD: you also may need to enable local forwarding:

```
awsuser@aws # ls echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet
```

Or instead of enabling it for all interfaces enable only on income interface:

```
awsuser@aws # ls echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/accept_local
```